# How to deal with this inequation with 3 absolute values?

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

> Solve:$$|x-2|+|3x+2|-x-2|x+4|\le -x-4$$

I am having trouble even starting with this inequation. Do I find out first the zeroes of each absolute value and then I would get intervals for each absolute value?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite your equation as
$$|x-2| + |3x+2| + 4 = 2|x+4|
\iff |-x+2| + |3x+2| + 4 = |2x+8|$$
Recall in the triangle inequality among $n$ real numbers $u_1,u_2,\ldots, u_n$,

$$|u_1| + \cdots + |u_n| \ge |u_1 + \cdots + u_n|,$$

the equality is achieved when and only when all non-zero $u_k$ have the same sign. Since
$$(-x + 2) + (3x +2) + 4 = 2x+8\quad\verb/and/\quad 4 > 0$$
the equation you have is equivalent to
$$-x + 2 \ge 0\;\;\verb/and/\;\; 3x + 2 \ge 0 \quad\iff\quad x \in \left[ -\frac23, 2\right]$$

Answer (score 1):

One way to go about this is to explicitly plot the graph of $$f(x) = |x-2|+|3x+2|-x-2|x+4| + x + 4$$
With some skill$\color{red}{^1}$, you should be able to see that in fact $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$. Thus, to solve $f(x) \le 0$ would be the same as finding the zeros of $f$, i.e. solving $f(x) = 0$. See the graph of $f$ below.

[image]

The set of values of $x$ which satisfy $f(x) = 0$ constitute the closed interval $$\left[-\frac{2}{3}, 2\right]$$
on the real line.

---

$\color{red}{1.}$ How would you plot the graph? Just consider what $f(x)$ looks like when $x \ge 2$, $-\frac23 \le x\le 2$ and $-4\le x\le -\frac23$. You should be able to obtain piecewise definitions of $f(x)$, and plot the graph. Even without plotting the graph it should be clear that $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$. Needless to mention, you can solve $f(x) = 0$ from the piecewise definitions too - quite easily.

If you need more details, or have any questions, please let me know.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I should just plot the graph of that same function and find out the zeroes? But how do I tell if the soulution does not include negative infinity and positive infinity in union?

Comment: You don't have to plot the graph, the graph is just for insight. See my comments towards the end. You can simply find the piecewise definition of $f(x)$ and continue. Also, about your question - positive and negative infinity are not even real numbers, so I don't know what you're talking about. @57_Pixels